# How to display post body example by default in swagger UI from azure functions(2.0)

Tags: c#, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.0, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm new to swagger open API documentation. Integrating the **Aliencube.AzureFunctions.Extensions.OpenApi.Core** in **azure function app 2.0**.

Here is the code :

```
    [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "TestFunction", tags: new[] { "TestFunction" })]
    [OpenApiRequestBody("text/plain", typeof(string))]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> TestFunctionRun([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,"post", Route = null)] HttpRequest TestFunctionRequest, ExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        {
           //definition of function
        }
    }
```

In Swagger it is displaying as below

[image]

we are expected to display below example value by default

```
{
  "username" : "testuser",
  "userid" : "1"
}
```

If the above Expected example value is displayed by default by using **AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle** in azurefunction 2.0. It is also help full for us.

Please help me out from this problem as we are running out of time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about changing attribute to `[OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(User))]`. Make sure to add the right class in `typeof`.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use， `Pet` is a model.

```
[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(Pet), Required = true, Description = "Pet object that needs to be added to the store")]
```

[image]

## Reproduce your problem:

[image]

[image]

## Solution:

[image]

[image]

## Reference

1. **Source code** ： [AzureFunctions.Extensions](https://github.com/aliencube/AzureFunctions.Extensions)
2. **Blog** : [Introducing Swagger UI on Azure Functions](https://devkimchi.com/2019/02/02/introducing-swagger-ui-on-azure-functions/)
3. set startup project.

   [image]